# How to add wildcard for email address in this exact format?

Tags: php

In this line `if ($email != "user@domain.com")` how do I change "user" to a wildcard?  The code must have the exact beginning format of `if ($email !=` in order to integrate with my script.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
The `!=` operator checks for the **exact** value.
There are no *string wildcards* in PHP.

You can use substr:

```
if( substr($email, -11, 11) != "@domain.com" )
```

Or RegExp:

```
if( preg_match('/@domain.com$/iu',$email) )
```

See [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) in PHP manual.

Comment: What is the code to have it remove the email instead of just finding it.  I am trying to remove email addresses with certain domains using a wildcard.